# cell array isn't supported by Matlab coder

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

I have a list of matrices. I want to use Matlab coder to get the corresponding c code and hence run the program faster. However, cell array is not supported in Matlab coder. Is there any other way to make a list of matrices so that Matlab coder supports the resulting list of matrices?

Comment: Can't you simply use an array of `mxArray` pointers, where each element would be a pointer to an `mxArray`?

Comment: I am not familiar with Matlab at all. I didn't get what `mxArray` is. Are there some examples?

Comment: Oh I'm very sorry.  I thought you wanted to write a MEX wrapper.  You want to use the MATLAB coder.  Please ignore what I said then!  I don't have much experience with MATLAB coder so I unfortunately don't have an answer to your question.  Hopefully, someone with more experience (Sam Roberts, chappjc, etc.) will be able to help you.

Comment: @yashar Are the sizes and data types of the matrices compatible so they could be concatenated together? Does the part of your code which is slow need cell arrays or could you factor it so that the computationally intensive part doesn't use cells?

Comment: @lilbill39 I tried to use multidimensional arrays and it seems it works.

Comment: @yashar Good to hear. So you were able to eliminate all of your cell array usage with that technique?

Comment: @lilbill39 yes I did. Still, I should inspect the code more to see if the results are correct otherwise there isn't any error when I run the code.

Comment: MATLAB V2017 version of Coder supports cell arrays.